# Magento 2 in iframe

Tags: magento2, iframe

I'm trying to show Magento 2 inside an iframe.
It was possible in Magento 1, as [explained in this guide](http://nwdthemes.com/2014/10/05/magento-not-working-in-iframe/).

Is it possible to use Magento 2 settings to allow showing it from iframe?

My current workaround:

```
cp /var/www/magento/app/etc/env{,_backup}.php
grep -v SAMEORIGIN /var/www/magento/app/etc/env_backup.php > /var/www/magento/app/etc/env.php
```

Comment: Would you mind asking a clear, more complete question than a one-liner please?

Comment: @Michael in iframe magento site login working ?

Answer (score 1):

We recommend against running Magento in an iFrame but to experiment with it, see [the documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/secy/secy-xframe.html).